# Pattern Matching on a Lifted Type (Slick Lifted Embedding)

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, slick, lifting

If I wanted to pattern match on a basic option type in Scala, I would run something along the lines of

```
val opt = Option(5)
val lessThanTen = opt match {
    case Some(e) => if (e < 10) true else false
    case None => None
}
```

But suppose that opt comes as a result of one of Slick's Queries, and therefore has the Lifted Embedding Type of `Rep[Option[Int]]`
How can I carry out the same pattern matching in a way that allows us the to see inside of the the lifted type? I.e. something along the lines of

```
val opt = Rep(Option(5))
val lessThanTen = opt match {
    case Rep[Some(e)] => Rep[if (e < 10) true else false]
    case Rep[None] => Rep[None]
}
```

But of course, one that compiles ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `map` method to apply some operation on the content of a `Rep`.

```scala
val rep: Rep[Option[Int]] = ???
val boolRep = rep.map {
    case Some(i) => Some(i < 10)
    case None => None
}
```

Even better: `Option`, like many other collection types in Scala, also has a similar `map` method, so you can write

`val boolRep = rep.map(_.map(_ < 10))`

In that expression, the first `_` is the `Option[Int]`, and the second one is the `Int` itself. In cases where the `Option[Int]` is `None`, the `map` method has nothing to apply the given function to, so it returns `None` by definition.

Comment: The Rep type doesn't actually have a 'map' function defined on it. This solution unfortunately does not work.

val rep: Rep[Option[Int]] = Some(3)
val boolRep = rep.map(_.map(_ < 10))

does not compile

Comment: You're right, I answered too fast. Can you describe what you are really trying to achieve rather than the subproblem you think you need to solve? I mean, in terms of database query, what do you want to do?